# Angular blocked cors

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, cors, preflight, blocked

In my localhost, I have disabled Google chrome security but know I want to deploy it in my Server and I have this cors problem.
The API is not from me, it's an external API.

[image: Cors Error Image]

My Service in Typescript is

```
getPlaces(holiday_type, currency, checkin, checkout, groups, page) {
    return this.http.get(
      `/api/v2/places?holiday_type=${holiday_type}&currency=${currency}&checkin=${checkin}&checkout=${checkout}&groups[]=${groups}&page=${page}`,
      {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': this.auth,
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
        },
      });
}
```

And my proxy.config looks so

```
{
  "/api/*":  {
    "target": "https://tr.halalbooking.com",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

Comment: `"changeOrigin":true` is missing in proxy.config. Did you try with it?

Comment: Yes, i have test it, but it was not success :/

Comment: In that case, you need a server side proxy. Run node at your end and call apiz calls from there and serve it for your frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like *halabookings* is blocking the request. You have two options:

1. Contact the owner of halalbookings and ask them to allow your origin. Often times, if they are providing you with an API, you have a portal where you can white list or specify the allowed origins.
2. Move the API call to halalbookings to take place server side. Then, in your front end, call your API (which calls halalbookings)

Comment: I want test it, thank you. If i it works i write back